# Why is my PHP query function not returning a result set when querying in a loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database class that creates a database instance upon page load which in itself creates a database connection as such:

```
class database{
       var $connection; 


       /* Class constructor */
       function database(){
          /* Make connection to database */
          $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Within this class I have a function that queries the database using the above connection like this:

```
function query($query){
      return mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
}
```

This works properly if I use this query function once in my php, but the second I put this query function call into a loop all but the first instance of the query function call return a null result set. Here is an example of the loop code that is not working:

```
$chartSQL = "CALL RESEARCH.INTRA_DAY_PRICE('".$row['TICKER_I']."', 7)";
$result = $database->query($chartSQL);
```

Could this have something to do with the fact that I am querying a MySQL routine and not a simple select statement? Note that the routine "INTRA_DAY_PRICE" is a select statement using the supplied argument. Could it maybe be that I am using the same connection in a loop and the connection is simply in use during each consecutive call, thus the null result set?

Edit: Here is the whole loop:

```
$search_term = sr_addslashes($_GET['search']);
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT t.TICKER_I, t.TICKER_C, t.TICKER_N, cpv.CURRENT_PRICE_A, cpv.MARKET_CAP, cpv.DA\
YS_CHANGE_A FROM ".DB_NAME.".TICKER_MyISAM t INNER JOIN ".DB_NAME.".CURRENT_PRICE_V cpv ON t.TICKER_I = cpv.TICKER\
_I WHERE t.INTEREST_F = 1 AND (MATCH(t.TICKER_C, t.TICKER_N) AGAINST('".$search_term."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR t.TICK\
ER_C = '".$search_term."' OR t.TICKER_N = '".$search_term."') LIMIT 20";

$results = $database->query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

               //Chart

               <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
               <script type="text/javascript">
               google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['annotatedtimeline']});
               function drawVisualization() {
               var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
               data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
               data.addColumn('number', '<?php echo $row['TICKER_C']; ?>');
               data.addRows([
               <?php
               $chartSQL = "CALL RESEARCH.INTRA_DAY_PRICE('".$row['TICKER_I']."', 7)";
               $result = $database->query($chartSQL);
               while($chartRow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                 echo $chartRow['FORMATTED'];
               }
               echo "null]);";
               ?>

               var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_d\
iv_<?php echo $count; ?>'));
               annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {'scaleType': 'maximized', 'displayRangeSelector': false, 'displayZoom\
Buttons': false});
               }
               google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
               </script>
               <div id="chart_div_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="chart_div"></div>

               <?php
                   // End Chart
}
```

Comment: Please provide the loop here.

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated and considered obsolete. You should strongly consider switching your code to use the PDO or mysqli libraries instead. (given that you have a DB class which I guess all your other code uses, this should be pretty straightforward)

Comment: We really need to see the code in context.

Comment: Sure I added the whole loop. I took out irrelevant code that I've confirmed is not the issue. Also - if I modify the query function to create a new connection each time it loops it does work, but it is very very slow.

Comment: @adear11 Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: I'm looking at it. There isn't anything jumping out at me that would be causing the behavior you are describing. However, I can't urge you enough to rewrite this using either PDO (my preference) or mysqli as @Spudley suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean to sound impatient I just wasn't sure if I had to tag you to send a notification - I guess I don't. Rewriting this using mysqli is something I will be doing very soon here, maybe that will fix the issue who knows.

Comment: Your query might be returning more than one result set... which I don't think the mysql* functions handle at all.  If you switch to mysqli you can use the mysqli_multi_query() and mysqli_next_result(): http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php